# How does the space in between texts scaled based on font-size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am supposed to convert List of element to single element with same **font-size, line-height** and **width**, I used to get this html elements while converting pdf to html using Apache PDFBOX and CSSBOX(no worry about viewport or screen dpi)

for ex:

```
[{inner-text:hai, font-size:13pt, line-height: 12.5pt, width: 20pt}, 
{inner-text:how, font-size:13pt, line-height: 12.5pt, width: 20pt}, 
{inner-text:are, font-size:13pt, line-height: 12.5pt, width: 20pt}, 
{inner-text:you, font-size:13pt, line-height: 12.5pt, width: 20pt}]
```

then i need to reduce these list of elements to single element with these inner texts, like

```
{inner-text: hai how are you, font-size:13pt, line-height: 12.5pt, width: 80pt}
```

While reducing to single element, I will aggregate the widths of individual element(like 20pt+20pt+20pt+20pt), but the total width is not enough to hold the aggregated texts because of space in between them, if i hard code space as 3pt it works but won't for bigger fonts.

Because the space varies when the font-size vary, So my question is...

How to determine the space between texts in point(pt)?? and

Is there any relationship present with Space in-between text's and font-size,

Please answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: removed "java" tag - does not look like related to "java language". javascript != java

Comment: I concluded that space between the words takes approximately 0.25 pt, if the font-size is 1 pt then the single space takes 0.25 pt, But it varies for individual font family, i.e it varies from 0.25 pt to 0.28 pt, So i calculated the space units by **font-size x 0.25** this might not be proper solution but fulfills by need.